# How to only create table if it doesn't exist? Using "object_id('table') IS NULL" doesn't work?

Tags: sybase

I would like to check if the table does not exist, then create one, otherwise, insert data into it.

```
use tempdb
if object_id('guest.my_tmpTable') IS NULL 
begin
   CREATE TABLE guest.my_tmpTable (
    id int,
    col1 varchar(100)
   )
end 

--- do insert here ...
```

The first time run, the table was created but the 2nd run the sybase complains the table already exist.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see it listed in sysobjects? (select * from sysobjects where name='my_tmpTable')

Answer (score 7):

The reason is that the entire statement - if and its "true" part are compiled as one.

If the table exists during compilation - error.

So you could put the `CREATE TABLE` statement into a dynamic sql statemetn `EXEC('CREATE TABLE....')`

Then all that Sybase sees at compilation is:

```
IF object_id('mytab') IS NULL
  EXEC('something or other')
```

The contents of `EXEC` are not compiled until execution, by when you know there's no table and all is well.