# Checking if table exist or not

Tags: java, sybase, sap-ase

I am retrieving data from database using jdbc. In my code I am using 3-4 tables to get data. But sometimes if table is not present in database my code gives exception. How to handle this situation. I want my code to continue working for other tables even if one table is not present. Please help.

I have wrote a code like this

```
sql="select * from table"
now Result set and all.
```

If table is not present in database it give exception that no such table. I want to handle it. In this code I cannot take tables which are already present in advance . I want to check here itself if table is there or not.

Please do not mark it as a duplicate question. The link you shared doesnot give me required answer as in that question they are executing queries in database not through JDBC code

Comment: post the relevant codes and the exception

Comment: How can a table be not present? As a programmer when you construct a query or ORM handler you should know which tables are present in the database, isn't it ??

Comment: edited mt question please have a look

Comment: capture the exception and process it as you wish. however, these exceptions are for that.

Comment: @alfasin please donot mark it as duplicate. It is some what different from it

Comment: @zaib7777 it looks exactly the same, what in your question is different?

Comment: @alfasin I have already edited my question to explain you why it is different and I am using Sybase which is much more different from mysql and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES don't work in it

Comment: Next time make sure to tag your question with the relevant label...

Comment: I have tagged with a relevant label. You should make sure to ask someone before marking someone's question as duplicate

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?); the system schemas are different across these products

Comment: Ase only not advantage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to only create table if it doesn't exist? Using "object\_id('table') IS NULL" doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974541/how-to-only-create-table-if-it-doesnt-exist-using-object-idtable-is-null)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Sybase ASE the easiest/quickest method would consist of querying the `sysobjects` table in the database where you expect the (user-defined) table to reside:

```
select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'table-name' and type = 'U'
```

- if a  record is returned => table exists
- if no record is returned => table does not exist

How you use the (above) query is up to you ...

- return a 0/1-row result set to your client
- assign a value to a @variable
- place in a `if [not] exists(...)` construct
- use in a `case` statement

---

If you know for a fact that there won't be any other object types (eg, proc, trigger, view, UDF) in the database with the name in question then you could also use the `object_id()` function, eg:

```
select object_id('table-name')
```

- if you receive a number => the object exists
- if you receive a NULL   => the object does not exist

While `object_id()` will obtain an object's id from the `sysobjects` table, it does not check for the object `type`, eg, the (above) query will return a number if there's a stored proc named 'table-name'.

As with the `select/sysobjects` query, how you use the function call in your code is up to you (eg, result set, populate @variable, `if [not] exists()` construct, `case` statement).

---

So, addressing the additional details provided in the comments ...

Assuming you're submitting a single batch that needs to determine table existence prior to running the desired query(s):

```
-- if table exists, run query(s); obviously if table does not exist then query(s) is not run

if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'table-name' and type = 'U')
begin
     execute("select * from table-name")
end
```

- `execute()` is required to keep the optimizer from generating an error that the table does not exist, ie, the query is not parsed/compiled unless the `execute()` is actually invoked

If your application can be written to use multiple batches, something like the following should also work:

```
# application specific code; I don't work with java but the gist of the operation would be ...
run-query-in-db("select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'table-name' and type = 'U'")
if-query-returns-a-row
then
    run-query-in-db("select * from table-name")
fi
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this. But to let you I can't use this. I have to check at runtime whether table exist or not. My code is such that it will make a table at runtime. and that tablename it will pass to sql statement as mentioned in my question. so, I think this is not the right solution for this particular problem.

Comment: As I mentioned, the basic code can be used in many ways depending on your requirements; Kostas' example shows basically the same thing for a conditional `create table`; I suggest you update your question with an example of exactly what you want to do a) if the table exists and b) if the table does not exist

Comment: if table exist my code will fetch data from DB but incase if it doesnot exist my code should not stop  processing it should continue ti process remaining code which is not dependent on this table which doesnot exist

Comment: I've added to my answer to address your latest comment/example; I still recommend you update your question to be more specific as to what you want to do when the table does (not) exist; as currently written ... "I want to handle it" ... does not tell us **how** you want handle it; also keep in mind that folks coming into this question have better things to do with their time than reading through all the comments and then try to piece together what is actually desired (ie, consolidate all of your comments/details in the question)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way of checking if the table exists and drop it:

```
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM sysobjects
  WHERE name = 'a_table'
  AND type = 'U'
)
DROP TABLE a_table
GO
```

And this is how to check if a table exists and create it.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM sysobjects
  WHERE name = 'a_table'
  AND type = 'U'
)
EXECUTE("CREATE TABLE a_table (
  col1 int not null,
  col2 int null
)")
GO
```

(They are different because in table-drop a temporary table gets created, so if you try to create a new one you will get an exception that it already exists)

Comment: I am using sybase INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES don't work in it

Comment: I am updating the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Before running the query which has some risk in table not existing, run the following sql query and check if the number of results is >= 1. if it is >= 1 then you are safe to execute the normal query. otherwise, do something to handle this situation.

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE (TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name') AND (TABLE_NAME = 'name_of_table')
```

I am no expert in Sybase but take a look at this,

```
exec sp_tables '%', '%', 'master', "'TABLE'"
```

[Sybase Admin](http://razorsql.com/articles/sybase_admin_queries.html)